# How to restrict access to an admin panel?

Tags: remote-access

I have an admin panel on the back of my website, and I wish to restrict public access to this, I know however if I do this then I will lose the remote access, which I want to keep.

I am running on a linux server with cpanel. Is it possible to restrict access to this dir without losing remote access?

I was told one could restrict IP access using VPN?

Comment: Doesn't cpanel have an option to password protect a specific directory (using .htaccess files)?

Comment: im not sure, i was thinking about restricting it using htaccess (too 1 IP only), but wasn't sure how secure this was.

Comment: Depending on how serious you are about security, we use the products from http://www.duosecurity.com/ on some of our admin back-ends in addition to IP and password based protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't there a login/password requirement to access the admin section?  Though it's not the most graceful solution, you could restrict by IP using htaccess.

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```